# Post request for an api works with restTemplate but throws proxy error with webClient

Tags: java, spring-webflux, apigee, spring-webclient

I'm trying to call an api with WebClient and it throws 404 with the below error message
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Unable to identify proxy for host: localhost:9943 and url: \/url\/post\/msg","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ApplicationNotFound"}}}
Below is the snippet where I'm trying to call the api

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .tcpConfiguration(client -> client
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
                .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10000))
                        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(10000))));
        ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
        WebClient webClient =  WebClient.builder().baseUrl("https://example.com").clientConnector(connector)
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                        .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024)).build())
                .build();       
        return webClient.post().uri(uriBuilder -> {
            URI url = uriBuilder.path(/postMsg).build();
            return url;
        }).headers(t -> {
            t.addAll(headers);
            
        }).body(Mono.just(request), Request.class)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> handleResponse(clientResponse));
```

Tried with and without proxy and it doesn't work.

But the same api works fine from postman and with restTemplate. Below is the snippet which works fine with restTemplate

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<Request> entity = new HttpEntity<Request>(request, headers);
        String response = restTemplate
                .exchange("https://example.com/postMsg", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class)
                .getBody();
```

request and headers are the same for both
webClient and restTemplate implementation.
Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated